Error [AxiosError]: Request failed with status code 400
I'm trying to create a banking app that allows users to connect to their banks via Plaid and fetch all details, including transactions. I have successfully integrated Plaid, and users can connect their accounts; however, there seems to be a problem when fetching the transactions; it keeps returning an error. Here is a part of my code:
export const getTransactions = async ({
  accessToken,
}: getTransactionsProps) => {
  let hasMore = true;
  let transactions: any = [];

  try {
    // Iterate through each page of new transaction updates for item
    while (hasMore) {
        const response = await plaidClient.transactionsSync({
          access_token: accessToken,
        });
        // const data = response.data;
  
        transactions = response.data.added.map((transaction) => ({
          id: transaction.transaction_id,
          name: transaction.name,
          paymentChannel: transaction.payment_channel,
          type: transaction.payment_channel,
          accountId: transaction.account_id,
          amount: transaction.amount,
          pending: transaction.pending,
          category: transaction.category ? transaction.category[0] : "",
          date: transaction.date,
          image: transaction.logo_url,
        }));
        
        hasMore = response.data.has_more;

    }
    return parseStringify(transactions);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("An error occurred while getting the accounts:", error);
  }
};

The error seems to be generated by line 160; below is the error log.
An error occurred while getting the accounts: Error [AxiosError]: Request failed with status code 400
    at async getTransactions (lib\actions\bank.actions.ts:160:25)
    at async getAccount (lib\actions\bank.actions.ts:101:25)
    at async Home (webpack-internal:\(rsc)\app\(root)\app\(root)\page.tsx:36:20)
  158 |     // Iterate through each page of new transaction updates for item
  159 |     while (hasMore) {
> 160 |         const response = await plaidClient.transactionsSync({
      |                         ^
  161 |           access_token: accessToken,
  162 |         });
  163 |         // const data = response.data; {
  code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST',
  config: [Object],
  request: [ClientRequest],
  response: [Object],
  status: 400,
  constructor: [Function],
  toJSON: [Function: toJSON]
}

I know this may not be much info, but I'm happy to provide anything if needed. Any assistance is greatly appreciated :)

Print the response body in the catch block to get more info. console.log(error.response.data)

The (bad) thing about axios is that it throws on non-OK responses.  A status code is just one more piece of data, and the error is confusing you, thinking that maybe your code is faulty.  Maybe it is, but most likely is not.  The server is telling you:  400 BAD REQUEST, the request you sent has problems in it.  Usually the body has details about what is wrong.

I added the console.log(error.response.data) to the catch block but it returned an error saying  'error' is of type unknown so I used this code instead
if(error instanceof AxiosError && error.response) {       console.log(error.response.data)     } else {       console.log('An unexpected error occurred:', error);     }
but nothing came back and the error still persisted :(

catch (error: any) { console.log(error.response.data); }
